# Using Redux, can any component get and set (by action) any data in the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Using Redux, is it true that any component and sub-component on the page get all data of the one and only store, and be able to send out any action at all, even if it is not meant for that component to send out?

Can all the components use

```
const store = createStore(mainReducer);
let state = store.getState();
```

and be able to see all states of the whole app?  Can any component dispatch any action all all?  So for example, if there is Counter component and a Comment component, can the Comment component accidentally send out a `"INCREASE_COUNT"` action?

Answer (score 1):

Using Redux any component "can" access any data in the store, but for the access you have to 'connect' it with the store. When you 'connect' you also specify a map to which part you want this component to access. That's how you are in control, it only gets access to what you want only.

The same goes for actions. You have to map the actions also - which component can dispatch which action, when your 'connect' to the store.

Check this out for more info - https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: can't any component do a `createStore(mainReducer); let state = store.getState();` and be able to access all the data?

Comment: or another way is use mapStateToProps and get more state which are the state of other components

Answer (score 1):

To most part of your question, it seems the answer is Yes.

Yes, the components can access the whole store ( one it has subscribed to ) and can dispatch actions when needed. I do not think there is any way you can put action/store behind some restrictions.

`can the Comment component accidentally send out an "INCREASE_COUNT" action?` Yes if you try to dispatch it again from the child component.

If you could add any specific example you have to ask, I can add more to my answer.

I hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

" every component has access to the store" is wrong, it is like this " every component has access to the state and actions in the store that you "the developer" specify.

for a component to able to access the store, you need to wrap it in the connection function like so

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// Your component

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchActionToProps);

// the component will only have access to the store props and actions that you specify
// in mapStateToProps and dispatchActionToProps

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  // state is the result of combineReducers
  // whatevery key the component needs you can specify here
  };
}

const dispatchActionToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
  // your store actions 
  };

}
```